# Can columns be linked in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to link two fields in a table so that one auto-increments, but resets to zero when the other field changes? For example, I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE searches(
searchID INT UNSIGNED NOT NUL,
userID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
searchParams VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
creationDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

INDEX(userID, searchID)
)ENGINE MyISAM;
```

The same user can create several searches, so what I want is to have searchID start at 1 whenever a new userID is entered, and increment automatically if a record to be inserted has a userID for which there are previous entries already. Can this be achieved somehow at table definition time? If not, can it be achieved with a single insert statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the benefit of restarting the `searchID` for each user over simply letting it increment?

Comment: `NOT NUL` you realize that's a typo.

Comment: maybe via a trigger? `ALTER TABLE searches AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;` since the trigger could be after change on the desired field seems like it should work

Comment: @user3783407 you missed something

Comment: The benefit is mainly that it allows me to save space. Due to the application specification, a user will hardly insert more than 4 or 5 searches, but the total amount of users will be high, so if I can reset the counter I can use a TINYINT vs an INT or bigger data type. Another benefit is that it might be useful for sorting the searches of a user, but this of course is something I can resolve in other (and maybe better) ways.

Comment: @user3783407, in my opinion that's entirely unnecessary. The space you save will be negligible, and sorting will work anyway. The complexity tradeoff vs. (very little) space savings isn't worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to link two fields in a table so that one
>   auto-increments, but resets to zero when the other field changes?

NO, there is none; unless you build a trigger and make this change happen. Though I don't see how this would be helpful considering that one is a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. You will unnecessary reseed it again and again.